# How to cross-platform install a package pipenv, method depending on the platform?

Tags: python, pipenv, shapely

I'm trying to install the [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) package to a cross-platform project using pipenv. However, on Windows, shapely can't be installed using a simple `pipenv install shapely`, it throws errors for a missing dependent dll. For this purpose, there is a pre-built wheel available from the famous [unofficial package wheels](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) by Christoph Gohlke:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
shapely = {file = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/n5jyqt7p/Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl", sys_platform = "== 'win32'"}

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

This wheel is perfect for Windows, but only for Windows. So how do I specify in a Pipfile that, *only* if the platform is linux, it can simply `pipenv install shapely` as:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
shapely = "==1.6.4.post2"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

or is this not possible using pipenv? Or do I hack together a `Pipfile.Windows` file that my unfortunate Windows colleague can rename to `Pipfile`?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wheel distribution is ok with linux as well, sorry, don't know you linux distro, but you can try this:

```
[packages]
# for linux
shapely = {file = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/36/1af447160f713d72f35dd7e749788367b7a13285c4af2fbd675128aa4e99/Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl", platform_system="Linux"}

# for windows
shapely_win = {file = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/n5jyqt7p/Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl", platform_system="Windows"}
```

`shapely_win` name doesn't affect package installation

Comment: This strategy appears to almost work, except I found out that the Windows URL does not to be stable. I can work around by hosting it somewhere myself. For today (the URLs seem to change on a daily (?) basis):
```
[packages]
shapely = {file = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/36/1af447160f713d72f35dd7e749788367b7a13285c4af2fbd675128aa4e99/Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl", platform_system = "== 'Linux'"}
shapely_win = {file = "https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/r7aykn4w/Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl", platform_system = "== 'Windows'"}
```

Comment: @cgohlke is it true that the libs on the UCI repository have no stable URL?

Comment: Hm, appears I can't reference SO users directly that aren't in the discussion yet...

Comment: you definitely can host your own whl package. And you can try to store your win/lin wheel fles locally and use `shapely = {file="file://your_local_path_to_pacakage"}` guess that will let to distribute them alongside you pipfile